# Subcategories are not listed in parent category page of MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki installed on a standalone server. I created many categories and organized all categories into a hierarchy with a single top level category.

In MediaWiki software, if the category contains subcategories, they should be listed under the content and above the list of the pages that are directly assigned to the parent category. But it does not happen in my installed software; subcategories are not listed on their parent category page. Does anybody know possible causes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could resolve the issue following an advice from [Ciencia Al Poder](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Ciencia_Al_Poder).

I contribute the answer here for those who may face the same issue.

***Background of the issue***: I imported categories from another wiki using Special:Export/Special:Import. 
Each category had several subcategories. I hoped that importing category from another wiki would preserve category's hierarchy. But that didn't work. The "categorylinks" table ([Manual:categorylinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table)) keeps category->subcategory relationships and hierarchy. But that table was not populated properly during the import.

***How the issue is resolved***: Since I imported lots of templates and categories using Special:Import, the job table ([Manual:job table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_table)) was populated with 20,000 records. Since one job is normally executed on each page load, regular site visits were not able to run that number of jobs in a short period of time. So I run php maintenance/runJobs.php script ([Manual:RunJobs.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RunJobs.php)) manually two times to be able to execute all jobs in the queue.  After that, I got all categories linked to each other in a hierarchy.